# BitmapFactory.decodeFile();

Tags: android, image

In my application, I have a file:

```
private File TEMP_PHOTO_FILE = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp_photo.jpg");
```

This is declared directly in my class, and is visible to all the methods there in.

I want to use this:

```
Bitmap thePhoto = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Uri.fromFile(TEMP_PHOTO_FILE).toString());
```

Uri.fromFile(TEMP_PHOTO_FILE).toString() generates the string: "file:///mnt/sdcard/temp_photo.jpg"

Why does this not work?  It seems that since we're dealing with a file, there should be some method of decodeFile() that accepts a URI as input.  Not allowing that is very frustrating due to the inconsistency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"file://" doesn't work. Try this:

```
Bitmap thePhoto = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(TEMP_PHOTO_FILE.getAbsolutePath().toString());
```